# Update/Add Array Value PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.invoice (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    json_data jsonb NOT NULL
);
```

My Data:

```
INSERT INTO public.invoice (id,json_data) VALUES
     (1,'{"Id": 1, "Items": ["2", "3", "1"], "Invoice": "CR000012"}');
```

**Todo List:**

1. Need to add to "Items" a new value i.e "5". (output of items `["2", "3", "1","5"]`)
2. Need to update items value 2 to 9. (output of items `["9", "3", "1","5"]`)

I have tried below but this will replace the array values not update or add

```
UPDATE invoice  SET json_data = jsonb_set(json_data, '{invoice }', '"4"') where Id ='1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use [this aproach](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-modify-arrays-in-postgresql), you should point element with index of array.

In your case, your code should look something like this,

**1. Add to Items a new value i.e "5**

`UPDATE invoice SET json_data = jsonb_set(json_data, {Items,0}, json_data->'Items' || '"5"', TRUE) where Id =1`

**2. Update Items value 2 to 9.**

`UPDATE invoice SET json_data = jsonb_set(json_data, {Items,0}, '"9"') where Id =1`

You can check PostgreSQL, JSON Functions and Operators from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html).